# property is not being assign to java-script object?

Tags: javascript, object

property myProperty is not assigned to variable foo, foo is an object.

```
var foo=null;//null is an object
foo.myProperty = "my value";
console.log(typeof foo.myProperty);
```

Comment: Your `null` object?

Comment: `TypeError: foo is null`

Comment: null is an object so property should be assign to it.

Comment: @anigalan: 1. you shouldnt try sth likethis. its simply bad style. 2. null is an object, string is an object, doesnt mean that you can simply add propertys

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript object should be declared like this

```
var myObject = {};
```

Try to modify you code like

```
var foo = {};
foo.myProperty = "a string";
console.log(typeof foo.myProperty);
```